# Deleted something and messed up Windows 10 experience

Tags: windows-10, start-screen

I have a laptop running Windows 10 and it was running out of space.  this folder:

> c:\users\glenn\appdata\Local\

was like 22GB, so i went hunting for the culprit.  I did find some stuff to delete, but I also deleted something I shouldn't have, I think.

I saw some files related to old Windows 10 apps in here, and so I thought it was a temporary file cache, and I cleared some of the files:

> C:\Users\Glenn\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0

And now the Start Button, and Cortana, and all of the items in the taskbar do not work.  All of the Windows 7ish stuff works well, as expected.  All of the Windows8/10ish stuff doesnt work.  I see this error message is the event viewer

> Activation of app
>   Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy!App failed with
>   error: The app didn't start. See the
>   Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational log for additional information.

This code `_cw5n1h2txyewy` found in the message above is shared by other apps in that apps folder, so I'm guessing I delete the Shell Experience Host app.

Awesome.

Is there away I can reinstall Windows from PowerShell or something?   I'm trying to figure out how to revert Windows without losing my files.

Help?  Anyone know where I can find the `Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational` logs?

Comment: The easiest way would be to create a new user profile. That’s of course provided you can still do that. You may have some luck using `mmc` to manage “Local Users and Groups”. Virtually all Windows logs are available in Event Viewer (also `mmc`-based).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, on my machine this folder weighs in at a whopping 0KB, so I don't think what you deleted was actually critical, although that doesn't explain why it stopped working for you.

The following command from an elevated powershell should reregister all the components that are failing:

`Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}`

As for the logs, you should be able to find these in Event Viewer, under:

`Applications and Services Logs\Microsoft\Windows\Apps\Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational event log.`

Comment: AppData\Local being empty is impossible.

Comment: @DanielB We're talking about `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0` aren't we?

Comment: Depends. ;) The `Apps` folder doesn’t even exist on my system.

Comment: that powershell command did the trick.  I think I have the Insider preview of Windows 10 Pro.  its basically an apps shortcut folder i think.

Comment: @DanielB Is that ... Negative... Bytes?? I'm confused :)

Comment: @GlennFerrie Glad it worked for you, don't poke too much more ;)

Comment: @Jonno that's what I do. I poke. I will try not to mess with it too much